# Is there any app to monitor how long has each app been actively used?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, applications

What I'm looking for is basically some monitoring application, which will log how long has each of my applications been actively used. By that I mean it got focus.

The point of this would be to monitor the workflow and to see where do I spend most time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com/tour) will do this. It will also break down your browser usage by site, which is useful too.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Active Timer](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/activetimer/) for this in the past.  [Wakoopa](http://social.wakoopa.com/) will do it as well, but you can't get a very detailed breakdown.